# How to do a select count query for this $sql?

Tags: php, count

I need this query:

```
$sql = "
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN DISTINCT 
       table1.pid, table1.fn, table2.did_id, table2.whodoc, table3.nname, table3.nid
FROM table1
JOIN table4 ON table1.pid = table4.pid 
JOIN table2 ON table4.did_id = table2.did_id
JOIN table3 ON table1.pid = table3.pid
WHERE kind = '$kind' 
  AND (
        (table3.nname LIKE '%$q%'
         OR table3.pat_notes LIKE '%$q%'
         OR table3.nid like '%$q%')
      )
ORDER BY table3.id DESC
LIMIT $startrow, 10
";
```

To be rewritten in this format:

```
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT * 
FROM some table 
LEFT JOIN other_table ON something.some_id = somesometable.somesomeid_id 
WHERE atable.a1field = '$something'
   OR the_atable.a2table_by = '$ok' 
  AND privacy = '$sorter'
  AND the_visit.why_visit LIKE '%$q%' 
   OR the_visit.height_onv LIKE '%$q%'
   OR the_visit.blood_pressure_onv LIKE '%$q%'
");

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: Please format your code for readability when posting a question. `:)`

Comment: Also, if you just need the number of rows, why not `SELECT COUNT(table1.pid)`?

Comment: i am sort of new not sure what to do in thise case.

Comment: If you just want the number of rows that would have been returned, count a primary or unique field. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html. I believe this would be more efficient than actually doing the search and counting using a PHP function.

Comment: Actually, sorry, that should be count the rows, not a primary/unique field. I was thinking of the `DISTINCT` keyword in the first query.

Answer (score 1):

Not having access to the actual data, I believe you could do something like this:

```
$sql = "
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN DISTINCT COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM table1
JOIN table3 ON table1.pid = table3.pid
WHERE kind = '$kind' 
  AND (
          table3.nname LIKE '%$q%'
       OR table3.pat_notes LIKE '%$q%'
       OR table3.nid like '%$q%'
)
";
```

Not real sure about the `STRAIGHT_JOIN` part, since I've not done that. But the rest I think should work.

Comment: As my note says, I don't know your actual database schema, but the idea is that you count each row returned (which is what `COUNT(*)` does). The result itself would be returned as a row with only one output, ie, `$result[0]['Count']`. So you have to retrieve it just like any other query.

Comment: If you have phpMyAdmin, try testing your query in there first. I find that helps me find errors in my code quicker when I'm trying to figure something like this out.

Comment: Also, you don't use `mysql_num_rows()`. That will always give you one row, because `COUNT()` is like a `SUM` function; it only returns one row with the result in the specific column(s).